# Displaying long CiviCRM multi select fields in a Drupal Webform

Tags: webform-civicrm

We have a circumstance where we have a multi select custom field with around 200 options. We then have this field loaded into a Drupal webform (for this project we need to use Webforms).

The standard Drupal Webform field options only allow either a CTRL click multi select or radio buttons, neither of which will work with that many options.

We have also tried a module called Chosen (https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) but have failed to get this to work with the Webform. Has anyone got any experience of getting Chosen working with Webforms or an alternative approach?

Oliver

Comment: Does [Multiselect](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiselect) work with Webform? Even then, this sounds like bad UX; an autocomplete widget or hierarchical select might be better.

Comment: Agree that Chosen is the way to go -- if you can't get it working with a standard Drupal Webform, you may want to post this in the Drupal StackExchange. (This issue may be related: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129489/webform-capability-issue-with-chosen )

Answer (score 3):

I've written a small module that allows you to use the select2 widget on your webforms:

https://github.com/colemanw/webform_select2

Enjoy!